# I'm given a matrix equation $XA = X - A$, where I know what $A$ is, how do I solve such a thing?

Tags: matrices

Here's the matrix $A$:

\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 2\\
2 & -2 & 3\\
-1 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}

How do I solve the matrix equation $XA = X - A$?

Comment: The equation can be rewritten as $A = X(I-A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is $XA = X - A$. This can be rewritten as follows:

$X - XA = A$

$X(I - A) = A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Multiplying by the inverse of $I - A$ on the right gives:

$X(I-A)(I-A)^{-1} = A(I-A)^{-1}$,

giving you $X = A(I-A)^{-1}$.

You can then just compute the right hand side.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Alright, but what does I stand for? As:
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
?

Comment: Or an Idenity matrix rather

Comment: $I$ is standard notation for the identity matrix. However this solution is incorrect, albeit only slightly.

Comment: @player3236 I'll take a look at your Solution, thanks in general <3

Comment: It's $X-XA=A\to X(I-A)=A\to X=A(I-A)^{-1}$ finally we get $$X=\frac{1}{11} \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -5 & 5 & 9 \\
 3 & -3 & 10 \\
 -1 & 1 & -7 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$